# Gooey GUI: How to store input files and call them after?

Tags: python, user-interface

In summary, I have some code that works from the command line that imports an excel file, transforms to a data frame, adds columns, changes some strings, and outputs an excel file. I am trying to adapt it to the Gooey GUI example to my code but I still do not understand how the original author managed to store the input file and transform it into a data frame.

This is my original code from the command line:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("accounting_file")

df.loc[df["Amount"] < 0 ,'Credit'] = df['Amount']
df.loc[df["Amount"] > 0 ,'Debit'] = df['Amount']

df.loc[df["Debit"].isnull() ,'Debit'] = 0
df.loc[df["Credit"].isnull() ,'Credit'] = 0
```

Now I want to get a GUI using Gooey that lets the user import the file to be used ("accounting_file") and run it through the df.loc transformation.

This is what I have so far adapted from an example code (reference: https://pbpython.com/pandas-gui.html)

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob
import os
import json
from argparse import ArgumentParser
from gooey import Gooey, GooeyParser

@Gooey(program_name="FEC")

def parse_args():
    stored_args = {}
    # get the script name without the extension & use it to build up
    # the json filename
    script_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(__file__))[0]
    args_file = "{}-args.json".format(script_name)
    if os.path.isfile(args_file):
        with open(args_file) as data_file:
            stored_args = json.load(data_file)


    parser = GooeyParser(description = 'FEC')
    parser.add_argument('data_file',
                        action='store',
                        default=stored_args.get('data_directory'),
                        widget='FileChooser',
                        help="Source directory that contains Excel files")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    # Store the values of the arguments so we have them next time we run
    with open(args_file, 'w') as data_file:
        # Using vars(args) returns the data as a dictionary
        json.dump(vars(args), data_file)
    return args

def dr_and_credits(data_file):
    df = pd.read_excel(args.data_file)
    df.loc[df["Amount"] < 0 ,'Credit'] = df['Amount']
    df.loc[df["Amount"] > 0 ,'Debit'] = df['Amount']

    df.loc[df["Debit"].isnull() ,'Debit'] = 0
    return df

if __name__ == '__main__':
    conf = parse_args()
    print("Done")
```

but it gives me the error " name `__file__` is not defined" referring to the line `script_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(__file__))[0]`

I have tried adding path and referencing path instead of `__file__`, like this:

```
path = 'Users\bxmart\Downloads\hello'
script_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(path))[0]
```

And it indeed runs the GUI, but it gives me the following error in the GUI window after I hit start:

```
IPython: an enhanced interactive Python shell.

Subcommands

-----------



Subcommands are launched as `ipython-kernel cmd [args]`. For information on
using subcommand 'cmd', do: `ipython-kernel cmd -h`.



install

    Install the IPython kernel


Options

-------



Arguments that take values are actually convenience aliases to full
Configurables, whose aliases are listed on the help line. For more information
on full configurables, see '--help-all'.


--debug

    set log level to logging.DEBUG (maximize logging output)

--quiet

    set log level to logging.CRITICAL (minimize logging output)

--init

    Initialize profile with default config files.  This is equivalent
    to running `ipython profile create <profile>` prior to startup.

--no-stdout

    redirect stdout to the null device

--no-stderr

    redirect stderr to the null device

--pylab

    Pre-load matplotlib and numpy for interactive use with
    the default matplotlib backend.

--autoindent

    Turn on autoindenting.

--no-autoindent

    Turn off autoindenting.

--automagic

    Turn on the auto calling of magic commands. Type %%magic at the
    IPython  prompt  for  more information.

--no-automagic

    Turn off the auto calling of magic commands.

--pdb

    Enable auto calling the pdb debugger after every exception.

--no-pdb

    Disable auto calling the pdb debugger after every exception.

--pprint

    Enable auto pretty printing of results.

--no-pprint

    Disable auto pretty printing of results.

--color-info

    IPython can display information about objects via a set of functions,
    and optionally can use colors for this, syntax highlighting
    source code and various other elements. This is on by default, but can cause
    problems with some pagers. If you see such problems, you can disable the
    colours.

--no-color-info

    Disable using colors for info related things.

--nosep

    Eliminate all spacing between prompts.

--matplotlib

    Configure matplotlib for interactive use with
    the default matplotlib backend.

--secure

    Use HMAC digests for authentication of messages.
    Setting this flag will generate a new UUID to use as the HMAC key.

--no-secure

    Don't authenticate messages.
--profile-dir=<Unicode> (ProfileDir.location)

    Default: ''

    Set the profile location directly. This overrides the logic used by the

    `profile` option.

--profile=<Unicode> (BaseIPythonApplication.profile)

    Default: 'default'

    The IPython profile to use.

--ipython-dir=<Unicode> (BaseIPythonApplication.ipython_dir)

    Default: ''

    The name of the IPython directory. This directory is used for logging

    configuration (through profiles), history storage, etc. The default is

    usually $HOME/.ipython. This option can also be specified through the

    environment variable IPYTHONDIR.

--log-level=<Enum> (Application.log_level)

    Default: 30

    Choices: (0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 'DEBUG', 'INFO', 'WARN', 'ERROR', 'CRITICAL')

    Set the log level by value or name.

--config=<Unicode> (BaseIPythonApplication.extra_config_file)

    Default: ''

    Path to an extra config file to load.

    If specified, load this config file in addition to any other IPython config.

--ip=<Unicode> (IPKernelApp.ip)

    Default: ''

    Set the kernel's IP address [default localhost]. If the IP address is

    something other than localhost, then Consoles on other machines will be able

    to connect to the Kernel, so be careful!

--hb=<Int> (IPKernelApp.hb_port)

    Default: 0

    set the heartbeat port [default: random]

--shell=<Int> (IPKernelApp.shell_port)

    Default: 0

    set the shell (ROUTER) port [default: random]

--iopub=<Int> (IPKernelApp.iopub_port)

    Default: 0

    set the iopub (PUB) port [default: random]

--stdin=<Int> (IPKernelApp.stdin_port)

    Default: 0

    set the stdin (ROUTER) port [default: random]

--control=<Int> (IPKernelApp.control_port)

    Default: 0

    set the control (ROUTER) port [default: random]

-f <Unicode> (IPKernelApp.connection_file)

    Default: ''

    JSON file in which to store connection info [default: kernel-<pid>.json]

    This file will contain the IP, ports, and authentication key needed to

    connect clients to this kernel. By default, this file will be created in the

    security dir of the current profile, but can be specified by absolute path.

--transport=<CaselessStrEnum> (IPKernelApp.transport)

    Default: 'tcp'

    Choices: ['tcp', 'ipc']

--autocall=<Enum> (InteractiveShell.autocall)

    Default: 0

    Choices: (0, 1, 2)

    Make IPython automatically call any callable object even if you didn't type

    explicit parentheses. For example, 'str 43' becomes 'str(43)' automatically.

    The value can be '0' to disable the feature, '1' for 'smart' autocall, where

    it is not applied if there are no more arguments on the line, and '2' for

    'full' autocall, where all callable objects are automatically called (even

    if no arguments are present).

--colors=<CaselessStrEnum> (InteractiveShell.colors)

    Default: 'Neutral'

    Choices: ['Neutral', 'NoColor', 'LightBG', 'Linux']

    Set the color scheme (NoColor, Neutral, Linux, or LightBG).

--logfile=<Unicode> (InteractiveShell.logfile)

    Default: ''

    The name of the logfile to use.

--logappend=<Unicode> (InteractiveShell.logappend)

    Default: ''

    Start logging to the given file in append mode. Use `logfile` to specify a

    log file to **overwrite** logs to.

-c <Unicode> (InteractiveShellApp.code_to_run)

    Default: ''

    Execute the given command string.

-m <Unicode> (InteractiveShellApp.module_to_run)

    Default: ''

    Run the module as a script.

--ext=<Unicode> (InteractiveShellApp.extra_extension)

    Default: ''

    dotted module name of an IPython extension to load.

--gui=<CaselessStrEnum> (InteractiveShellApp.gui)

    Default: None

    Choices: ['glut', 'gtk', 'gtk2', 'gtk3', 'osx', 'pyglet', 'qt', 'qt4', 'qt5', 'tk', 'wx', 'gtk2', 'qt4']

    Enable GUI event loop integration with any of ('glut', 'gtk', 'gtk2',

    'gtk3', 'osx', 'pyglet', 'qt', 'qt4', 'qt5', 'tk', 'wx', 'gtk2', 'qt4').

--pylab=<CaselessStrEnum> (InteractiveShellApp.pylab)

    Default: None

    Choices: ['auto', 'agg', 'gtk', 'gtk3', 'inline', 'ipympl', 'nbagg', 'notebook', 'osx', 'pdf', 'ps', 'qt', 'qt4', 'qt5', 'svg', 'tk', 'widget', 'wx']

    Pre-load matplotlib and numpy for interactive use, selecting a particular

    matplotlib backend and loop integration.

--matplotlib=<CaselessStrEnum> (InteractiveShellApp.matplotlib)

    Default: None

    Choices: ['auto', 'agg', 'gtk', 'gtk3', 'inline', 'ipympl', 'nbagg', 'notebook', 'osx', 'pdf', 'ps', 'qt', 'qt4', 'qt5', 'svg', 'tk', 'widget', 'wx']

    Configure matplotlib for interactive use with the default matplotlib

    backend.

--cache-size=<Int> (InteractiveShell.cache_size)

    Default: 1000

    Set the size of the output cache.  The default is 1000, you can change it

    permanently in your config file.  Setting it to 0 completely disables the

    caching system, and the minimum value accepted is 3 (if you provide a value

    less than 3, it is reset to 0 and a warning is issued).  This limit is

    defined because otherwise you'll spend more time re-flushing a too small

    cache than working

--ident=<CUnicode> (Session.session)

    Default: ''

    The UUID identifying this session.

--user=<Unicode> (Session.username)

    Default: 'username'

    Username for the Session. Default is your system username.

--keyfile=<Unicode> (Session.keyfile)

    Default: ''

    path to file containing execution key.

To see all available configurables, use `--help-all`

[IPKernelApp] CRITICAL | Bad config encountered during initialization:
[IPKernelApp] CRITICAL | Unrecognized flag: '--ignore-gooey'
```

Comment: If you want to use a `FileChooser` instead of a `DirChooser` you can just do... that. replace them...

Comment: @Tomerikoo does it change how you call the input file? because I still don't understand how that is done

Comment: You will obviously have to change alot of the logic of the code. For example: in the function `combine_files`, the loop goes over all files of the format `sales-<anything>.xlsx` and appends them to one big dataframe. If you want one file instead, what do you expect to do with it? maybe I missed something in the question

Comment: basically I already have the code that works from the command line that: imports an excel file, transforms to a data frame, adds columns, changes some strings, and outputs an excel file --> now I want to get a GUI to import the file from the user using FileChooser, apply the code automatically (when Start button is pressed for example) and output and excel file like the author of the example did with def save_results(sales_data, output) function

Comment: @Tomerikoo basically yes! and run it through the transformations, which I believe are very straight-forward to add (like creating a function def transfrom() or something and writing the transformation code in there). But I have no idea how to call that file after the user chooses it

Comment: You can change the argument of the `parser` to be `'data_file'` instead of `'data_directory'` and change from `DirChooser` to `FileChooser`. Then you have the `args` object returned from `parse_args` function and you can access the file chose by the user by doing `args.data_file`. And then do with it whatever you want

Comment: I really want to better help you but it seems that there are two entities here: the code you are referencing from (that is attached) and code you are actually using (that is missing). I think it will be more helpful if you posted here the actual code **you** are trying to use, and the reference code to be attached as a link for reference for us because it sounds like you are trying to do something quite different from the tutorial. So, leave the link above, but replace the code with yours

Comment: I edited the question the way you suggested! Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: It seems like the errors you listed above has to do with the fact that you are running from `IPython`. Try to run it a script through `cmd` or something similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically it sounds like the example script you're using is a bit of an overkill for your purposes. According to the details you provided and what you are trying to do it looks like this could be a good outline code to start with:

```py
import pandas as pd
from gooey import Gooey, GooeyParser

@Gooey(program_name="My program")
def parse_args():
    parser = GooeyParser()
    parser.add_argument('data_file',
                        action='store',
                        widget='FileChooser',
                        help="Source Excel file")
    parser.add_argument('out_file',
                         widget='FileChooser')

    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args

def transform(file):
    df = pd.read_excel(file)
    # do your transformation on the file
    return df

def save_results(df, file):
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file, engine='xlsxwriter')
    df.to_excel(writer)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = parse_args()
    input_file = args.data_file
    output_file = args.out_file
    output_df = transform(input_file)
    save_results(output_df, output_file)
    print("Done")
```

The whole part with the `script_name` and `json` and the `stored_args` is a way to always use the arguments that were passed in the last run as defaults to the current run. This might not be necessary for you, and anyway I would recommend leaving it at least until you get the basic version up and running. This can be a nice feature to add later, first concentrate on getting it to work.

Comment: Thanks! when running it on idle I got the error ImportError: Missing optional dependency 'xlrd'. Install xlrd >= 1.0.0 for Excel support Use pip or conda to install xlrd. However, I pip and conda installed it and still get the same error

Comment: I am guessing this is a dependency to write dataframes back to Excel. I'm sorry but I don't have specific experience with `pandas` and its dependencies

Comment: it's working after some troubleshooting! Thanks very very much!!

Comment: do you also have a solution for when users input multiple files? such as having two parser.add_argument()...I understand you use the name file to call upon the file the user inputs, but how do you differentiate between files when there are two or more spaces to enter files?

Comment: In the same manner. Create another argument with a different name for each file you need and access it in the same way. I will update my answer to demonstrate that also